# Matlab: printing symbolic equations

Tags: matlab

I have a symbolic equation a la 2x + 3y +4z = 0. The problem is I want to PRINT this to the screen along with complete sentences I'm typing. I want this to show in the terminal: "The equation for the rectifying plane is: 2x + 3y + 4z = D." I'm new to Matlab and having trouble finding a function suitable for this!

Thanks,
Snake

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [CHAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/char.html) method for symbolic objects to convert them to strings and the [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) function to print the strings to the screen. Here's an example:

```
syms x y z;        %# Define symbolic variables
eq = 2*x+3*y+4*z;  %# Create symbolic equation
fprintf('The equation for the rectifying plane is: %s = D.\n',char(eq));
```

And this will display the following:

```
The equation for the rectifying plane is: 2*x + 3*y + 4*z = D.
```

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understand your waitings, there are several ways, you can do it on this way, in case you want just to print

```
syms x y z;
q = 2*x + 3*y + 4*z;

disp('Displayed equation :');
pretty(q);
```

Or try to use `pretty_equation()`

Comment: `pretty_equation` is not part of the standard matlab. Are you refering to [this function](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55477-pretty-equation-viewer) from the matlab file exchange?

Answer (score 0):

```
disp('is what you are looking for?');
```

Comment: Hmmm, almost, but is there any way I can put in C-like %i arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `fprintf(args...)` is a function in MatLab, and my brief search on Google supports this.
Look into it.

Comment: Awesome, found a way to implement that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well certainly Matlab has commands similar to C with slight changes, and if you want to use %i. You can use the similar format of C's printf command which would be fprintf, but i think this would print also on any instrument along with it.

For full format look as:

```
               fprintf(fileID, format, A, ...)
```

here in format you can specify %i

also check full details by writing fprintf by pressing F1.

Comment: When you have enough reputation to do so, come back and upvote this and accept this as an answer.